# Database Query inside doGet of servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Is it OK to include database querying in doGet() of servelts ? Or shall those be put in other classes which are called from doGet() method ?

Comment: its better to include ur db methods in other classes.

Comment: Can you please share some link with example. Or some other details on how we should do that. I mean if I a simple use case of fetching employee information, per say, shall I create a db class - EmployeeInfo with a method and then call that method from Servlet ?

Comment: Look into a [Service Layer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162399/how-essential-is-it-to-make-a-service-layer) and [Data Layer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220909/service-layer-vs-dao-why-both). Your Servlets should call into the Service Layer, which call into the Data Layer. The Data Layer will call the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as functionality is concerned, you won't face any challenge if you are querying db for pull / push operations on data but ideally as suggested by 'BwithLove' above one should avoid doing so.

The reason for this is clear separation of business logic. While working with servlets one can easily go for MVC (Model, View and Controller) Design Approach which suggest clear separation of logic.

Now, what we actually mean by clear separation of logic?

Model: Model's basically confine to the bean or pojo clasess.

View: View will confine to your UI. Which will display data set by controller.

Controller: this is where we are delegating the requests. It will simply get the request and after assumpted logic from the business layer, it will display the result in View.

Business Layer will have the DAO which help you to perform push/pull operations as per your need.

Following such patterns, simply make easy coding strategy and supports flexibility in terms of future changes in the code. However, its always the developer's choice to leave it or follow it. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with querying DB from doGet method of servelts.

But having such operations in a separate class is good practice. You can call that operation from any action if it is in separate class.